# How to set up an authorization token in localStorage in Nuxt so that it disappears at the end of the browser session?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, local-storage, auth-token

The site uses the standard nuxt authorization with the use of cookies and localstorage.

When logging in, the user has the "Remember me" checkbox, respectively, if it is disabled, it is expected to log out of the account at the end of the browser session.

The default cookie timeout is session, but using localstorage to store auth tokens at the same time leaves the user logged in.

/config/auth.js

```
export default {
  watchLoggedIn: true,
  strategies: {
    local: false,
    customStrategy: {
      _scheme: '~/schemes/customScheme',
      endpoints: {
        login: {
          url: '/v2/dashboard/auth/login',
          method: 'post',
        },
        logout: false,
        cookie: {
          prefix: '',
        },
        token: {
          prefix: '',
        },
        localStorage: {
          prefix: '',
        },
      },
      tokenName: 'sp-api-key',
      tokenRequired: true,
      globalToken: true,
      tokenType: '',
    },
```

Is there a way to set the length of storage of authorization tokens in local storage for a time equal to the browser session? Or delete authorization tokens from localStorage after the end of the browser session?

Comment: You should use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) instead of localStorage if you want it to be automatically deleted at the end of a session

Comment: Can I use this storage if the user has not given permission for the use of cookies or has disabled them? Or is the session not covered by the EU Cookie Directive?

Comment: I don't know exactly but I assume it's the same as cookies or local storage, indexed DB, cache storage etc. I don't think the regulations care about what type of tech you use to store data

Comment: Note that using these storage methods just to remember an auth token would probably fall under "legitimate interest" and not require consent

Comment: Thank you. I also thought about this, in this case, for correct work, I can simply deactivate the storage of tokens in local storage and simply adjust the storage time for them in cookies.